# Can I use tabular parameters in Kusto user-defined functions

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Basically I'd like to pass in a set of field values to a function so I can use in/!in operators. I'd prefer to be able to use the result of a previous query rather than having to construct a set manually.

As in:

```
let today = exception | where EventInfo_Time > ago(1d) | project exceptionMessage;
MyAnalyzeFunction(today)
```

What is then the signature of MyAnalyzeFunction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions

For instance, the following will return a table with a single column (`y`) with the values `2` and `3`:

```
let someTable = range x from 2 to 10 step 1
;
let F = (T:(x:long)) 
{
    range y from 1 to 3 step 1
    | where y in (T)
}
;
F(someTable)
```